# Filter on inner map key and value pair in order to sum on an attribute value

Tags: java, java-8

I am learning java 8 streams and want to understand how to accomplish the below

I have a map of map and I want to apply filter on attributes on the attributes within the keys of the map of maps

```
class RegionDate {
LocalDate regionDate;
String region;
}

enum StudentType {
ACTIVE,
INACTIVE;
}

class Score {
double grade;
 boolean isValid;
 }
```

Collection that I have

```
Map<RegionDate, Map<StudentType, List<Score>>> groupedTotals
```

- i) I want to filter for a date that matches the localdate in
  RegionDate key
- then filter on the StudentType to be active on the
  inner map key
- then filter on the isValid attributes on the list
  of scores
- do a sum of the grade attribute to return the sum of
  grades of students for a date and type and having valid scores.

I tried a few options but I am not clear how to get to the inner map and access the key and values and filter on them. I end up building a Steam of Map after the first filter and then how do I filter on the key of the second map and the values as well?

```
 groupedTotals
.entrySet().stream()
.filter(e -> e.getKey().date().equals(date))
//filter on inner map key for student Type Active
//filter on inner map values for isValid is true
.filter(s -> s.isValid())
.map(v -> v.grade())
.mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
.sum();    //return a sum of the double values of all grades
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
groupedTotals
 .entrySet().stream()
 .filter(e -> e.getKey().date().equals(date)) // same so far
 .map(Entry::getValue) // get out the Map<StudentType, List<Score>>
 .map(m -> m.get(StudentType.ACTIVE)) // get the List<Score>
 .filter(Objects::nonNull) // remove nulls from maps without ACTIVE
 .flatMap(List::stream) // get just a Stream<Score>
 .filter(Score::isValid) // filter the valid scores
 .mapToDouble(Score::grade) // map directly to double
 .sum() // sum results
```

Comment: Please also explain what you changed, why this code works and the OP's doesn't

Comment: @user: The OP's code is incomplete and is well aware.  The parts I _changed_ are just simpler; the OP's code would work fine, but can be simplified.

Comment: I see, but an explanation of how it works would still be nice.